# Mouse Location + Amount IntersectsWith Button

Tags: vb.net, cursor-position

I have the cursor invisible and when a user scrolls over a button it highlights. The problem is when a user is in between buttons, he does not know where his cursor is.

On the mouse leave event I want the cursor to jump to the closest button (not the one he just left)

```
   Private Sub btnNumbers_Mouseleave(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAlef.MouseLeave, btnBkspc.MouseLeave, btnBack.MouseLeave, btnClearAll.MouseLeave, btnDeleteWord.MouseLeave, btnEditMenu.MouseLeave, btnUndo.MouseLeave, btnSpeak.MouseLeave, btnGimel.MouseLeave, btnZayin.MouseLeave, btnYud.MouseLeave, btnVav.MouseLeave, btnTzadik.MouseLeave, btnTuf.MouseLeave, btnTes.MouseLeave, btnSpace.MouseLeave, btnShin.MouseLeave, btnSamech.MouseLeave, btnReish.MouseLeave, btnQuestion.MouseLeave, btnPred5.MouseLeave, btnPred4.MouseLeave, btnPred3.MouseLeave, btnPred2.MouseLeave, btnPred1.MouseLeave, btnPeriod.MouseLeave, btnPercent.MouseLeave, btnOpenParen.MouseLeave, btnNun.MouseLeave, btnMem.MouseLeave, btnLetterPrediction2.MouseLeave, btnLetterPrediction1.MouseLeave, btnLamed.MouseLeave, btnKuf.MouseLeave, btnHey.MouseLeave, btnFey.MouseLeave, btnExclamation.MouseLeave, btnEnter.MouseLeave, btnEnderTzadik.MouseLeave, btnEnderNun.MouseLeave, btnEnderMem.MouseLeave, btnEnderFey.MouseLeave, btnEnderChaf.MouseLeave, btnDollar.MouseLeave, btnDaled.MouseLeave, btnCloseParen.MouseLeave, btnChes.MouseLeave, btnChaf.MouseLeave, btnBkspc.MouseLeave, btnBeis.MouseLeave, btnAyin.MouseLeave, btnApostrophe.MouseLeave, btn9.MouseLeave, btn8.MouseLeave, btn7.MouseLeave, btn6.MouseLeave, btn5.MouseLeave, btn4.MouseLeave, btn3.MouseLeave, btn2.MouseLeave, btn1.MouseLeave, btn0.MouseLeave, btnSavedPhrases5.MouseLeave, btnSavedPhrases4.MouseLeave, btnSavedPhrases3.MouseLeave, btnSavedPhrases2.MouseLeave, btnSavedPhrases1.MouseLeave, btnSettings.MouseLeave, btnPhrases.MouseLeave, btnNumbers.MouseLeave, btnMinimize.MouseLeave, btnHebrew.MouseLeave, btnExit.MouseLeave, btnCopy.MouseLeave, btnRightWord.MouseLeave, btnRightChar.MouseLeave, btnLeftWord.MouseLeave, btnLeftChar.MouseLeave, btnHome.MouseLeave, btnEnd.MouseLeave, btnT8.MouseLeave, btnT7.MouseLeave, btnT6.MouseLeave, btnT5.MouseLeave, btnT4.MouseLeave, btnT3.MouseLeave, btnT2.MouseLeave, btnT1.MouseLeave
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard
    Dim GetCursorPos = Cursor.Position
    If FormSettings.chbxBorderHover.Checked = True Then
        For Each c As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
            If GetCursorPos.IntersectsWith(c.Bounds) Then
                Cursor.Position = c.Location
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

This is what I have so far, however `intercectsWith` does not work with a drawing point

Is there any way for my to check what the closest button is?

Comment: change your logic to test if the bounds (Rect) contains the point: `if c.Bounds.Contains(Cursor.Position)`  you may have to convert the cursor to form coords first

Comment: As you loop through the controls, you would have to compute the distance between Cursor.Location and c.Bounds and find the one with the closest distance.  if c.Bounds.Contains(Cursor.Position) then the cursor is already in the control and you don't have anything to do.

Comment: @dwilliss how would i do that?

Comment: How to find the distance of a point to a rectangle http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44483/how-do-i-calculate-distance-from-a-point-to-a-rectangle

Comment: @BradleyUffner how would I change that code to vb? and what do x and y represent in that answer?

Comment: The `x` and `y` represent the top left coord of a rectangle. `px` and `py` are the coords of the point you are checking.  The return value is the distance of the point from the bounds of the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the interface will be **hard to use** (especially if the buttons are not large enough), but here's another implementation:

```
Private Sub btnNumbers_Mouseleave(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAlef.MouseLeave, btnBkspc.MouseLeave, btnBack.MouseLeave, btnClearAll.MouseLeave, btnDeleteWord.MouseLeave, btnEditMenu.MouseLeave, btnUndo.MouseLeave, btnSpeak.MouseLeave, btnGimel.MouseLeave, btnZayin.MouseLeave, btnYud.MouseLeave, btnVav.MouseLeave, btnTzadik.MouseLeave, btnTuf.MouseLeave, btnTes.MouseLeave, btnSpace.MouseLeave, btnShin.MouseLeave, btnSamech.MouseLeave, btnReish.MouseLeave, btnQuestion.MouseLeave, btnPred5.MouseLeave, btnPred4.MouseLeave, btnPred3.MouseLeave, btnPred2.MouseLeave, btnPred1.MouseLeave, btnPeriod.MouseLeave, btnPercent.MouseLeave, btnOpenParen.MouseLeave, btnNun.MouseLeave, btnMem.MouseLeave, btnLetterPrediction2.MouseLeave, btnLetterPrediction1.MouseLeave, btnLamed.MouseLeave, btnKuf.MouseLeave, btnHey.MouseLeave, btnFey.MouseLeave, btnExclamation.MouseLeave, btnEnter.MouseLeave, btnEnderTzadik.MouseLeave, btnEnderNun.MouseLeave, btnEnderMem.MouseLeave, btnEnderFey.MouseLeave, btnEnderChaf.MouseLeave, btnDollar.MouseLeave, btnDaled.MouseLeave, btnCloseParen.MouseLeave, btnChes.MouseLeave, btnChaf.MouseLeave, btnBkspc.MouseLeave, btnBeis.MouseLeave, btnAyin.MouseLeave, btnApostrophe.MouseLeave, btn9.MouseLeave, btn8.MouseLeave, btn7.MouseLeave, btn6.MouseLeave, btn5.MouseLeave, btn4.MouseLeave, btn3.MouseLeave, btn2.MouseLeave, btn1.MouseLeave, btn0.MouseLeave, btnSavedPhrases5.MouseLeave, btnSavedPhrases4.MouseLeave, btnSavedPhrases3.MouseLeave, btnSavedPhrases2.MouseLeave, btnSavedPhrases1.MouseLeave, btnSettings.MouseLeave, btnPhrases.MouseLeave, btnNumbers.MouseLeave, btnMinimize.MouseLeave, btnHebrew.MouseLeave, btnExit.MouseLeave, btnCopy.MouseLeave, btnRightWord.MouseLeave, btnRightChar.MouseLeave, btnLeftWord.MouseLeave, btnLeftChar.MouseLeave, btnHome.MouseLeave, btnEnd.MouseLeave, btnT8.MouseLeave, btnT7.MouseLeave, btnT6.MouseLeave, btnT5.MouseLeave, btnT4.MouseLeave, btnT3.MouseLeave, btnT2.MouseLeave, btnT1.MouseLeave
    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard

    If FormSettings.chbxBorderHover.Checked = True Then
        Dim currentPos As Point = Me.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
        Dim closestButton = (From x In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
                        Where x IsNot btn
                        Order By PointToButtonDistance(currentPos, x) Ascending).FirstOrDefault
        Cursor.Position = closestButton.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0))
    End If
End Sub

Private Function PointToButtonDistance(ByVal pt As Point, ByVal btn As Button) As Long
    Dim center As New Point(btn.Location.X + btn.Width / 2, btn.Location.Y + btn.Height / 2)
    Dim dx As Integer = Math.Max(Math.Abs(pt.X - center.X) - btn.Width / 2, 0)
    Dim dy As Integer = Math.Max(Math.Abs(pt.Y - center.Y) - btn.Height / 2, 0)
    Return dx * dx + dy * dy
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim minDist As Double = Double.MaxVal
Dim closestCtrl as Control = Nothing
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
    If c Is sender Then Continue For  ' Skip the one we came from

    Dim dist = ComputeDistance(Cursor.Position, c.Bounds)
    If dist < minDist Then
        minDist = dist
        closestCtrl = c
    End If       
Next
```

...

```
   ' Compute distance between 2 points
   Private Function ComputeDistance(x1 as Integer, y1 as Integer, x2 as Integer, y2 as Integer) as Double
        Dim dx = (x1 - x2)
        Dim dy = (y1 - y2)
       Return Math.Sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
    End Function

   ' Compute distance between a point and the closest corner of a rectangle
   ' I'm going to do this a lazy way. There's probably a better one
   Private Function ComputeDistance(pt as Point, rect as Rectangle) as Distance
        Dim dist as New List(of Double)
        dist.Add(ComputeDistance(pt.x, pt.y, rect.Left, rect.Top)
        dist.Add(ComputeDistance(pt.x, pt.y, rect.Right, rect.Top)
        dist.Add(ComputeDistance(pt.x, pt.y, rect.Left, rect.Bottom)
        dist.Add(ComputeDistance(pt.x, pt.y, rect.Right, rect.Bottom)
        Return dist.Min()
   End Function
```

Comment: Well, ignore my compute distance function now.  See the one Bradly posted a link to while I was typing my reply.  But the logic for finding the _closes_ button is still what you want.